# I can't fix camera to any object in a 2D Matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, camera, xna, viewport

**Problem description:** I am trying to develop some 2D game with terrain collision in C# using XNA framework. I have already completed simple terrain generating and object, for example car, can move on this terrain. But now, I get a problem with camera fix to that car. I tried to search a lot on web, but I can't find the right solution for me. When I run the program, it crash.

**What I tried?** I tried to run this program in debug mode and I always stay stuck with `NullReferenceException` in Camera constructor.

**piece of Camera.cs**

```
public class Camera {
            public Matrix transform;
            private Viewport view;
            private Vector2 centering;

        public Camera(GraphicsDevice view)
        {
            this.view = view.Viewport;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime, TheGame theGame)
        {
            centering = new Vector2(theGame.movement.position.X + theGame.movement.position.Y / 2);
            transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)) *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centering.X, -centering.Y, 0));
        }
    }
```

**camera instance call:**

```
    private Camera camera;
    public TheGame(Game game)
    :base(game)
    {
        this.game = game;
        camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice); //<---- here is the crash
    }
    private Game game;
```

**My question:** How to make camera fixed on any object in the Matrix or what is the standard way to do that, because I think that knowledge is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `NullReferenceException` is because `GraphicsDevice` is *not initialized yet*.

Instead of creating your `Camera` in the `TheGame` constructor, create it in the `Initialize` method:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
    camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice);
}
```

---

> How to make camera fixed on any object in the Matrix or what is the standard way to do that, because I think that knowledge is very important.

I'm assuming you are dealing with screen space coordinates where X grows from left to right and Y grows from top to bottom. I'm also assuming that the camera position indicates the top left corner of the camera view and camera is position at {0, 0} in local space.

Based on these assumptions and knowing the position of the entity you want to center your camera on, we can calculate the camera translation transform as following:

```
transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(
    theGame.movement.position.X - view.Width / 2f, 
    theGame.movement.position.Y - view.Height / 2f, 
    0));
```

This transform says: "*position the camera's top left corner on game object and subtract half of the camera's viewport to center it*".

Note that you might also want to clamp the camera's coordinates between 0 and game world size to ensure that camera doesn't go out of the bounds of game worlds using `MathHelper.Clamp`.

Comment: `public override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize();
            camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice);
        }`
This doesnt work for me. But thank you for answer.

Comment: What error do you get? Change `public` to `protected`.

Comment: Okey thank it works now ive fixed it but the Camera.cs is wrong now.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I made a couple of assumptions. If that doesn't work, then it'd be helpful if you also posted your `Draw` method.

Comment: `centering = new Vector2(movement.position.X + movement.position.Y / 2 - Game.width / 2, movement.position.Y);
            
transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 0))*
                        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centering.X, -centering.Y, 0));`
I did it like this but thank you for solution of my problem. Game is the class that have static width and height of Window.